# How do I use the command line to check which WiFi network I am connected to?

Tags: raspbian, wifi

I'm doing a headless setup, where we use the Pis in field work (tracking movement of seals via camera in the Cape Cod area), and so we can only monitor it headless, without a separate display (to save on power).
In order to have the Pis get time, I need them to connect to my colleague's iPhones (which are operating as hotspots), and use ntpd to get time from the internet.
However, I haven't yet figured out what the command is to query the WiFi network name, to confirm that it is connected to the right network - is there one?

Comment: Your job sounds awesome! Where can I learn more about your work?

Comment: Our lab website: runstadlerlab.mit.edu :D

Personal website: ericmajinglong.com

Answer (score 80, accepted):

`iwgetid` will give you the SSID

Answer (score 32):

Try iwconfig:

```
user@host:~ $ iwconfig
wlan0     unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated
          Sensitivity:0/0
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code to check the IP assigned to the RPi:

```
t="$(ifconfig wlan0 | awk '/inet addr/{print substr($2,6)}')"
echo $t
w=${#t}
echo $w
```

Comment: It wasn't asked for the IP address.

Comment: That code does not work on Raspian/RaspiOS Buster. The awk fails to match the output from `ifconfig`.